# C# How to increase value in every second and the increment value is based on amount.text file

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, textview, text-files

The IDE is Visual Studio 2010.

I have two text file called total-cost.txt and amount.txt
The file inside look like below:

```
total-cost.txt
4500000

amount.txt
600
```

The first text file (total-cost.txt) represents the total cost which will display at textbox(textbox name is totalcost).

A second file (amount.txt) represents the increment value for every second.

I'm trying to display the total of cost from total-cost.txt and auto increase the value in every second that set in the amount.txt

For example:

4500000 after 1 second become 4500600 after 2 second 4501200 and so on.

If I change the amount.txt value from 600 to 700 it become

4500000 after 1 second become 4500700 after 2 second 4501400 and so on.

The value will keep it refresh and display latest total cost only.

The issue is that I already display the total-cost value in textbox but I do not know how to increment a value that set by amount.txt

The coding I have done is in below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;

namespace new_countdown
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {         
        private string TotalCost;
        private int TotalFont;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ReadTotalCostFile()
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("total-cost.txt");
                TotalCost = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void UpdateDisplay() 
        {
            if (totalcost.Text != TotalCost)
            {
               totalcost.Text = TotalCost;
            }

            if (totalcost.Font.Size != TotalFont && TotalFont != 0)
            { 
                this.totalcost.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",(float)TotalFont,System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold,
                System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,((byte)(0)));
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateDisplay();
            ReadTotalCostFile();
        }
   }
}
```

Somehow, I just have done the display total cost in the textbox.

I have no ideas to do for auto-increment.

Have anyone share the idea or solution. I have much appreciated it.

Comment: Hello, please try to post only relevant code snippets instead of a whole class for readability.

Comment: @Stefan  Okay, i just want to make it clear as well as I can. Next time i will be noticed. Thanks you.

Comment: What's the purpose of C language tag if you don't use C?

Comment: @Gerhardh I have been amended. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

private void IncrementInt32ValueInFile(string filePath)
{
    var currentFileText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    if (int.TryParse(currentFileText, out int integerValue))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, Convert.ToString(++integerValue));
    }

    throw new Exception($"Incorrect file content. Path: {filePath}"); // If value in file can't be parsed as integer
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response.  I do not understand the code, can you have little explain? what is the filePath mean, is all the filePath I need to replace? If yes, which file should I replaced and where do I add this code in my full code. Thanks.

Comment: @Kim `filePath` is an argument for your `amount.txt` file path.

Just insert this method into your class and use it where you want

Comment: Okay. Is look like for example:
  private void IncrementInt32ValueInFile(string filePath)
        {
             var currentFileText = File.ReadAllText("amount.txt");
           if (int.TryParse(currentFileText, out int integerValue))
        {
            File.WriteAllText("total-cost.txt", Convert.ToString(++integerValue));
         }

         throw new Exception("Incorrect file content. Path: {filePath}"); // If value in file can't be parsed as integer
           } 
If I am doing wrong, please amend it. Thanks.

Comment: @Kim yes, but why you don't want to use `filePath` argument and replaced it directly in `File.ReadAllText` method?  

Example of usage:
`IncrementInt32ValueInFile("amount.txt");`

Comment: Dear picolino, I still cannot work fine in my program... could you willing to help me to look my coding via email? If bring any inconvenient, you may ignore it. Thanks.